# Django RF, unable to pass user instance to serializer.save() method

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a blog project where auth.users can Post new posts. When sending POST message to server it is unable to add loggedin user with new posts.

VIEWS.PY

```
class PostListCreate(APIView):
    parser_class = (FileUploadParser,)
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]

    def post(self,request):
        #postAuthor = self.request.user
        serializer = PostSerializers(data=request.data,context={'request':request})
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data,status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

SERIALIZER.PY

```
class PostSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    comments = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(many=True,read_only=True,view_name = 'comment_details')
    likes_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    user_has_voted = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
   # postAuthor = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
        #exclude=('voters',)

    def get_likes_count(self, instance):
        return instance.voters.count()

    def get_user_has_voted(self, instance):
        request = self.context.get("request")
        return instance.voters.filter(pk=request.user.pk).exists()
```

ERROR MESSAGE

```
{
    "postAuthor": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

MODELS.PY

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    file = models.FileField(null=True,blank=True)
    postAuthor = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='posts')
    voters = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                    related_name="votes",blank=True)
```

Comment: Can you show the post and author model? You probably need to specify who is the author of the post because in the model, the author field require it

Comment: sure,I updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem should be in meta class:

all the fields are required, but postAuthor is not passed with input data.

```
class PostSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    comments = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(many=True,read_only=True,view_name = 'comment_details')
    likes_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    user_has_voted = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
   # postAuthor = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
        #exclude=('voters',)

    def get_likes_count(self, instance):
        return instance.voters.count()

    def get_user_has_voted(self, instance):
        request = self.context.get("request")
        return instance.voters.filter(pk=request.user.pk).exists()
```

in your serializer, change

```
fields = '__all__'
```

to

```
exclude=('postAuthor',)
```

and in views, change

```
if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
```

to

```
if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(postAuthor=request.user)
```

this should help

Comment: Thanks Sachin, awesome...  Why should I remove it from meta class ? Because when I do posting new posts with user data ,shouldn't  it be there to serialize user data ?

Comment: if you pass postAuthor id along with the request data, you can use your code,

but in this case, the postAuthor is always the logged in user, so we avoid postAuthor from request data and assign the logged in user as postAuthor.

Answer (score 1):

```
    def post(self, request):
        request.data["postAuthor"] = request.user
        serializer = PostSerializers(data=request.data, context={'request': request})
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Try this.

Comment: Thanks but still I get error, I am using sessions auth with DRF browsable API, will that may be an issue ?

Comment: No, I do not think that would be an issue.

Comment: when I add new post through Django admin, in the postAuthor field it asks for user email id ,then post become success

Comment: serializer.save(postAuthor=request.user.email)
I changed it but still gets same error

Comment: @AnoopKGeorge can you update your post method and try?